# Modify uploaded images ASP.Net Core

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core-3.1, image-resizing

I'm developing a web app using ASP.NET Core 3.1, which will be running on Ubuntu server.
I used/installed Lazzia/LazZiya image resizer to reduce uploaded images size, crop and add my own watermark and save it when uploaded by user. Looks easy and complete.

But on Ubuntu it has some errors (some photos larger than 100 KB can't be managed in my case and some images are OK).

[LazZiya.ImageResize on GitHub](https://github.com/LazZiya/ImageResize/issues/1)

I need some alternatives, simple, complete and fast to manage uploaded images on my server side.

> on linux , an exceptions was throw:
>
> Parameter is not valid. at System.Drawing.Bitmap.SetResolution
> ............

Comment: Can you share the details of the error?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Error added/update. Same problem exists : `https://github.com/LazZiya/ImageResize/issues/1#issuecomment-586585752`